# Running multiple Grunt tasks of the same task type

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I need to be able to run multiple tasks of the same type of task within Grunt (grunt-contrib-concat).  I've tried a couple of things below but neither work.  Any ideas on how to do this are appreciated.

```
concat: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            'js/foo1/bar1.js',
            'js/foo1/bar2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/foo1.js',
        src: [
            'js/foo2/bar1.js',
            'js/foo2/bar2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/foo2.js'
    }
}
```

and..

```
concat: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            'js/foo1/bar1.js',
            'js/foo1/bar2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/foo1.js'
    }
},
concat: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            'js/foo2/bar1.js',
            'js/foo2/bar2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/foo2.js'
    }
}
```

and..

```
concat: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            'js/foo1/bar1.js',
            'js/foo1/bar2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/foo1.js'
    },
    dist: {
        src: [
            'js/foo2/bar1.js',
            'js/foo2/bar2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/foo2.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918202/using-grunt-to-concat-many-files-from-many-dirs-into-single-renamed-file-in-new?rq=1

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First define two targets for the task:

```
concat: {
    dist1: {
        src: [
            'js/foo1/bar1.js',
            'js/foo1/bar2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/foo1.js'
    },
    dist2: {
        src: [
            'js/foo2/bar1.js',
            'js/foo2/bar2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'js/foo2.js'
    }
}
```

Then register a new task that runs both:

```
grunt.registerTask('dist', ['concat:dist1', 'concat:dist2']);
```

Then run using

```
grunt dist
```

Comment: Some of the grunt plugins (ex grunt-phpunit) do not support targets.  See https://github.com/SaschaGalley/grunt-phpunit/issues/27

Comment: I found that keeping my watch task unchanged (as [concat]) worked too - it automatically went through both dist1 and dist2

Comment: hi , i have this error, Verifying property concat.dist1 exists in config...ERROR

Comment: Can you help anyone for me?

Comment: @Angu Please submit a new question.

Comment: @jgillich .. can you check my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424008/how-to-use-grunt-concat