# Grunt concat for each module then minify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Trying to do this with Grunt. 
I have a file structure like this:

```
/app
--app.js
--/module1
----module1.js
----module1Model.js
--/module2
----module2.js
----module2Model.js
```

How can I concatenate & minify each module into one file so it looks like:

```
/app
--app.min.js
--module1.min.js
--module2.min.js
```

We want this to be scalable so when we add module3, 4 it'll still work.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: See globbing patterns at this page: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

Answer (score 0):

you can use uglify for solution and "dist" and "src" can be changed according to use:

```
uglify:{
        liveproject:{
            files:{
                'dist/js/main.min.js' : ['src/js/*.js'],
                'dist/js/m1.min.js' : ['src/js/easing.js','src/js/modernizer.js'],
            }   

        }

    },
```

Comment: I tried something like this at first but it wasn't really scalable as I needed to specify each module.

Answer (score 0):

I derived my answer from this post: [Using grunt to concat many files from many dirs into single renamed file in new directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918202/using-grunt-to-concat-many-files-from-many-dirs-into-single-renamed-file-in-new)

```
grunt.registerTask('prepareModule', 'process dist module for concat', function() {

        //get configured concat task object
        var concat = grunt.config.get('concat') || {};

        //iterate through all file/folders at build/src/app/
        grunt.file.expand(grunt.config('build_dir') + '/src/app/*').forEach(function(dir) {

            //grab the last path name
            var dirName = dir.substr(dir.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            //filter for folders only
            if (dirName.slice(-3) !== '.js') {

                //add target for each module
                concat[dirName] = {
                    src: [grunt.config('build_dir') + '/src/app/' + dirName + '/*.js'],
                    dest: grunt.config('dist_dir') + '/src/app/' + dirName + '/' + dirName + '.js'
                };
            }
        });

        grunt.config.set('concat', concat);

    });
```