# grunt unused - loop subfolders in directory

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I am attempting to remove all unused image links within multiple subdirectories using [grunt-unused](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-unused). Here is my folder structure for clarity:

```
|-- dist
|  |-- site-1
|  |  |—-index.html
|  |  |—-style.css
|  |  |—-app.js
|  |  |—-image1.jpg
|  |  |—-image2.jpg
|  |  |—-image3.jpg
|  |  |—-image4.jpg
|  |-- site-2
|  |  |—-index.html
|  |  |—-style.css
|  |  |—-app.js
|  |  |—-image1.jpg
|  |  |—-image2.jpg
|  |  |—-image3.jpg
|  |  |—-image4.jpg
|  |-- site-3
|  |  |—-index.html
|  |  |—-style.css
|  |  |—-app.js
|  |  |—-image1.jpg
|  |  |—-image2.jpg
|  |  |—-image3.jpg
|  |  |—-image4.jpg
```

I have wrote a 'forEach' function to target these child folders and then reference each folder, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009874/dynamic-mapping-for-destinations-in-grunt-js) but it is not working for the unused task. It does not loop through each directory and console detects no unused files in a very quick time, like it is not actually doing anything.

Where am I going wrong?

```
grunt.registerTask('prodOutput', function () {

    // read all subdirectories of dist/ folder, excluding the assets folder
    grunt.file.expand('dist/*', '!dist/assets/**').forEach(function (dir) {

        //get the current unused config
        var unusedConfig = grunt.config.get('unused') || {};

        //set options for grunt-unused, including the folder variable 'dir' as the reference of where to look
        unusedConfig[dir] = {
            option: {
                reference: dir + '/',
                directory: ['**/*.css', '**/*.html', '**/*.js'],
                remove: false, // set to true to delete unused files from project
                reportOutput: 'report.txt', // set to false to disable file output
                fail: false // set to true to make the task fail when unused files are found
            }
        };

        grunt.config.set('unused', unusedConfig);

    });

    grunt.task.run('unused');

});
```

Comment: The main issue is you are dynamically configuring multiple [Targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) in your `forEach` Function prior to running the task, however `grunt-unused` does not support multiple target configs. To help better understand your requirement:..  Do the folders named `site-1`, `site-2` etc, potentially include unused assets (I.e. the assets in the `site-1` folder may not be linked/referenced in the `index.html` - also stored in the same folder)?. In which case, if they're not linked in `index.html` you want to delete the actual file?

Comment: Hi Rob,thanks for posting. Yes, site-1, site-2 etc will potentially have unused images in and not be linked to in any way. I am running another task just before this that is cooying in a master '/image' folder's contents that contains all images for all of the sites (site-1, site-2 etc.) Is there any other way you could think of that I could achieve this, as it would save a LOT of manual work by me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue

As mentioned earlier in my comment...  The main issue is that you are dynamically configuring multiple [Targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) in your `forEach` Function prior to running the task, however [grunt-unused](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-unused) does not support multiple target configurations.

Also `grunt-unused` expects the files that include references/links to other files (i.e. `index.html`) to be in a different directory/folder than the files it references (e.g. images, css, etc), however the folder structure provided in your post is flattened.

---

#### Solution

After a quick look around at other grunt plugins there doesn't seem to be one that will meet your requirement. The only way I think you can achieve this is to write your own custom Task/plugin to handle this.

To achieve this you could do the following:

Create a separate Javascript module that exports a [Registered MutliTask](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registermultitask). Name the file `delete-unused.js` and save it to a directory named `tasks` which resides in the same top level directory as your `Gruntfile.js`.

**Directory structure**

Your directory structure should be something like this:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── site-1
│   ├── site-2
│   ├── ...
│   └── assets
│
├── Gruntfile.js
│
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
│
├── package.json
│
└── tasks
    └── delete-unused.js
```

**delete-unused.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  'use strict';

  // Requirements
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');

  grunt.registerMultiTask('unused', 'Delete unused assets', function() {

    // Default options. These are used when no options are
    // provided via the  initConfig({...}) papaparse task.
    var options = this.options({
      reportOutput: false,
      remove: false
    });

    var reportTxt = '';

    // Loop over each src directory path provided via the configs src array.
    this.data.src.forEach(function(dir) {

      // Log if the directory src path provided cannot be found.
      if (!grunt.file.isDir(dir)) {
        grunt.fail.warn('Directory not found: '.yellow + dir.yellow);
      }

      // Append a forward slash If the directory path provided
      // in the src Array does not end with one.
      if (dir.slice(-1) !== '/') {
        dir += '/';
      }

      // Generate the globbin pattern (only one level deep !).
      var glob = [dir, '*'].join('');

      // Create an Array of all top level folders (e.g. site-*)
      // in the dist directory and exclude the assets directory.
      var dirs = grunt.file.expand(glob).map(function(dir) {
        return dir;
      });

      // Loop over each directory.
      dirs.forEach(function(dir) {

        // Add the folders to exclude here.
        if (dir === './dist/assets') {
          return;
        }

        // Log status and update report
        grunt.log.write('\nProcessing folder ' + dir);
        reportTxt += '\nProcessing folder ' + dir;

        // Empty Array to be populated with unused asset references.
        var unused = [];

        // Define the path to index.html
        var pathToHtml = [dir, '/', 'index.html'].join('');

        // Create Array of file names and filepaths (exclude index.html)
        var assets = grunt.file.expand([dir + '/**/*.*', '!index.html'])
          .map(function(file) {
            return {
              fpath: file,
              fname: path.basename(file)
            };
          });

        // Log/Report missing 'index.html' and return early.
        if (!grunt.file.exists(pathToHtml)) {
          grunt.log.write('\n  >> Cannot find index.html in ' + dir + '/\n');
          reportTxt += '\n  >> Cannot find index.html in ' + dir + '/\n';
          return;
        }

        // Read the contents of index.html.
        var html = fs.readFileSync(pathToHtml, {
          encoding: 'utf8'
        });

        // Loop over each file asset to find if linked in index.html
        assets.forEach(function(asset) {

          // Backslash-escape the dot [.] in filename for RegExp object.
          var escapedFilename = asset.fname.replace('.', '\\.');

          // Dynamically create a RegExp object to search for instances
          // of the asset filename in the contents of index.html.
          // This ensures the reference is an actual linked asset and
          // not plain text written elsewhere in the document.
          //
          // For an explanation of this Regular Expression visit:
          // https://regex101.com/r/XZpldm/4/
          var regex = new RegExp("(?:href=|src=|url\\()(?:[\",']?)(.*"
              + escapedFilename + ")[\",',\\)]+?", "g");

          // Search index.html using the regex
          if (html.search(regex) === -1 && asset.fname !== 'index.html') {
            unused.push(asset); // <-- Not found so add to list.
          }
        });

        // Log status and update report
        grunt.log.write('\n  ' + unused.length + ' unused assets found:\n');
        reportTxt += '\n  ' + unused.length + ' unused assets found:\n';

        //Delete the unused asset files.
        unused.forEach(function(asset) {
          if (options.remove) {
            grunt.file.delete(asset.fpath);

            // Log status and update report
            grunt.log.write('  deleted: ' + asset.fpath + '\n');
            reportTxt += '  deleted: ' + asset.fpath + '\n';
          } else {
            // Log status and update report
            grunt.log.write('    ' + asset.fpath + '\n');
            reportTxt += '    ' + asset.fpath + '\n';
          }
        });

      });

      if (options.reportOutput) {
        grunt.file.write(options.reportOutput, reportTxt);
      }

    });
  });
};
```

**Gruntfile.js**

Configure your `Gruntfile.js` as follows.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  'use strict';

  grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
    unused: {
      options: {
        reportOutput: 'report.txt',
        remove: true
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['./dist/']
      }
    }

  });

  // Load the custom multiTask named `unused` - which is defined
  // in `delete-unused.js` stored in the directory named `tasks`.
  grunt.loadTasks('./tasks');

  // Register and add unused to the default Task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    // ...
    'unused',
    // ...
  ]);

  // Or add it to another named Task.
  grunt.registerTask('foobar', [
    // ...
    'unused',
    // ...
  ]);

};
```

**Notes**

1. The `grunt-unused` plugin is no longer used, so you can uninstall it by running the following via your CLi tool: `$ npm un -D grunt-unused`
2. The `delete-unused.js` custom module provides a similar configuration in `Gruntfile.js` with less options than those found in `grunt-unused`. The `src` Array in the config accepts a path(s) to the folder  to be processed *(i.e. `./dist/`)*. and not a glob pattern - the glob pattern is generated inside `grunt-unused.js`.
3. The default options for `reportOutput` and `remove` are set to `false` in `grunt-unused.js`. When you first run the Task I recommend that you initially set the `remove` option to `false` in your `Gruntfile.js` configuration. This will simply log to the console the unused assets and allow you to check whether it meets your requirement. Obviously setting the `remove` option to `true` will delete any unused assets when it's re-run.
4. I noticed that in your post you provided the glob pattern `'!dist/assets/**'` to exclude the `assets` folder from being processed. Instead of passing the glob pattern to exclude via the `src` configuration this has been hard-coded in `delete-unused.js`. You'll see it in the lines that read:

```js
// Add the folders to exclude here.
if (dir === './dist/assets') {
    return;
}
```

If there are additional directories inside the `dist` folder that you want to exclude you'll need to add them there: For example:

```js
// Add the folders to exclude here.
if (dir === './dist/assets'
    || dir === './dist/foo'
    || dir === './dist/quux') {
    return;
}
```

5. This solution checks whether the assets found inside the `site-*` folders are linked/referenced inside the corresponding `index.html` only and does not check whether they are referenced in any `.css` file.
6. `delete-unused.js` utilizes a Regex to find whether the asset is actually linked to the `index.html` and is not as plain text written elsewhere in the document *(inside a paragraph of text for example)*. An explanation of the custom Regular Expression used can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/XZpldm/4/).

I hope this helps !

Comment: This is working - and your assumptions on certain parameters like my flat folder structure are 100% correct - thank you. I am blown away at the level of work you have done for this. I will mark this as the answer shortly, I had a little go at trying to add a way to check css references for completeness, however have failed. I dont expect you to add that part, but what would be your high-level approach at adding this?